# react MUI TextField inside react-hook-form Controller inside MUI Stepper-Dialog setValue not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I have a Button that opens a MUI Dialog.
Inside the Dialog I have a MUI Stepper. My Form is split up into different parts. Some Inputs are required others are not.

```
//Example Input
<Controller
    name="stateName"
    control={control}
    rules={{ required: true }}
    render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
      <TextField
        required
        label="stateName"
        variant="standard"
        onChange={onChange}
        value={value}
        fullWidth
        error={errors.stateName ? true : false}
        helperText={errors.stateName ? "Pflichtfeld" : null}
      />
    )}
  />
```

Full Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-tdd-dkzoqy

When I submit my form I add an entry to an existing list and display it alongside with an edit-Button.
If the edit-Button gets pressed I want to open the Dialog and have the Inputs filled with the values of the edited data.

I tried using react-hook-form `setValue("field", value)` but it is not working.
I also tried to pass the edit-object via Props to the nested form-steps and use `setValue` inside these components `useEffect` utilizing `useFormContext()` but it didn't work either.

How can I pass the values to the Inputs so they get correctly displayed in the Multi-Step-Form-Dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working CSB -> https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-chaum-znt71c?file=/src/App.tsx

In editHandler, state is a json string, so the simplest fix is to parse it into the object

```js
  const editHandler = (stateJSON: any) => {
    const state = JSON.parse(stateJSON)
    methods.reset(state);
```

But in submitHandler data is stringified, the submitHanlder should look smth like this:

```
  const submitHandler = (data: any) => {
    setContent(prevContent => [...prevContent,data] );
    methods.reset();
    setEditState(undefined);
    setOpen(false);
  };
```

Also checkout this out https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-objects-in-state

and

how to avoid mutations https://www.educative.io/courses/simplifying-javascript-handy-guide/B6yY3r7vEDJ